# Follow file rename programmatically

Tags: java, mercurial

How can I follow file rename when I have a filename/path at a certain revision and I want it at another one ?
Let's say we have a repository with these changeset:

Revision 0:

```
$ hg add test.txt
```

Revision 1 :

```
$ hg mv test.txt README.txt
```

Revision 2 :

```
$ hg add main.cpp
```

Revision 3 :

```
$  hg mv README.txt README
```

For example I have this data: `README.txt @ rev 2`.
How can I know that this file was `test.txt @ rev 0` ? and `README @ rev 3` ?

For now, I'm using hg4j and a "complex" algorithm (about 100 lines) that I could paste there if you want, but my question is : is there a better/direct way to do it?

Comment: It seems to me, that hg4j has the ability to do this with its "history" functionality (http://code.google.com/p/hg4j/wiki/HgLog)

Comment: Yes but we need to provide the path to the file in the current revision for it to work, but in my example the current path is unknown.

Comment: It looks like mercurial doesn't have built-in way to do it.  Even `hg log -f README.txt` at rev 2 gives changes made before rev 2.